# ng-model is not updated in ng-if

Tags: angularjs

I'm failing to retrieve the actual value of my selected option (ng-model=filter) in my select html bloc.

Note that if I don't set $scope.filter then $scope.filter stay undefined even if I select an option in the dropdown list.

**My html template, filters.html :**

> `<div ng-if="!showFilterTemplatePlz">
>       <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showFilterTemplate()" type="button">Add Filter</button>
>   </div>
>   <div ng-if="showFilterTemplatePlz" class="inline">
>       <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="closeFilters()" type="button">Close filters</button>
>       <label>filters</label>
>       <select ng-model="filter" ng-options="filter.name for filter in filterOptions" class="form-control">
>       </select>
>       <p>{{filter.name}}</p>
>       <button ng-click="addFilter()" id="addFilterButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</button>
>   </div>`

**In my directive:**

> ```
>       .directive('filters', ['retrieveStaticDatasService','usersService', function(datasService, usersService) {
>         return {
>             restrict: 'E',
>             scope: false,
>             controller: function ($scope) {
>                 /* init */
>                 $scope.filterOptions = [
>                     {name: "languages"},
>                     {name: "nationality"},
>                     {name: "location"}
>                 ];
>                 $scope.filter = $scope.filterOptions[0];
>                 /* end init */
>                 $scope.showFilterTemplate = function(){
>                       $scope.showFilterTemplatePlz=true;
>                 }
>                 $scope.closeFilters = function(){
>                     $scope.showFilterTemplatePlz=false;
>                 }
>                 $scope.addFilter = function(){
>                     console.log("filter to add : " + $scope.filter.name);                        
>                 }
>             },
>             templateUrl: '/partials/components/filters.html'
>         }
>     }])
> ```

**Result** :

I can see the actual value appears in my html but i will always show "languages" for$scope.filter.name in my console, whatever option I selected! I took a screenshot to show you : http://hpics.li/4a37ae3

Thanks for your help.

[Edit : I made some test and my model are setted and updated only if they are not inside the "`<div ng-if="..."></div>`"]. Is it not allowed to put a ng-if directly in the directive?

**Answer** : [Angularjs ng-model doesn't work inside ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342917/angularjs-ng-model-doesnt-work-inside-ng-if)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem was that ng-if creates a child scope. So I changed filter to **$parent.filter** in

```
 <select ng-model="$parent.filter" ng-options="option.name for option in filterOptions" class="form-control">
      </select>
```

Comment: "ng-if creates a child scope" that sentences saved me days of work

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing it by having to objects named 'filter'. You might be overwriting the ng-options object rather than your controller one.

Try changing to

```
<select ng-model="filter" ng-options="option.name for option in filterOptions" class="form-control"></select>
<p>{{filter.name}}</p>
<button ng-click="addFilter()" id="addFilterButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</button>
```

Comment: I just tried but it still not working, I also tried with another name instead of filter with no result... I will edit my post because I didn't say that this is in a directive and maybe the problem comes from that fact.

Comment: The problem comes from that my ng-model are inside a ng-if but I don't know why. Anyone has an idea?