# data-ng-model not updating with data-ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a html like this

```
<select data-ng-model="selection">
    <option value="">Select Search</option>
    <option value=1>One</option>
    <option value=2>Two</option>
    <option value=3>Three</option>
</select>
<input type="text" placeholder="search One" data-ng-model="search.one" data-ng-if="selection==1"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="search Two" data-ng-model="search.two" data-ng-if="selection==2"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="search Three" data-ng-model="search.three" data-ng-if="selection==3"/>
Selected: {{selection}}
Search by: {{search}}
```

In the above code, If an option is selected, the text box associated with that option is visible. But, if some input entered in the text box, the variable `search` ('search by' field in above code) is not getting updated. but if I delete `data-ng-if`, then `search` variable is getting updated properly.

What should I do to get `search` variable updated with `data-ng-if`?

Thank you!

Comment: possible for duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342917/angularjs-ng-model-doesnt-work-inside-ng-if

Comment: @gauravbhavsar: It worked for me. Now I am unsure what to do. Should I delete this question? or can you post this as answer and I'll accept...

Comment: you can not delete questions which have answers given, if you do this your account is blocked to ask question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution [Angularjs ng-model doesn't work inside ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342917/angularjs-ng-model-doesnt-work-inside-ng-if)

You have to use `$parent` to refer parent scope.

```
data-ng-model="$parent.search.one"
data-ng-model="$parent.search.two"
data-ng-model="$parent.search.three"
```

Answer (score 0):

try `data-ng-model="$parent.search.one"`

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because directives like ng-if, ng-repeat, ng-switch, ng-view and ng-include all create new child scopes.

To prevent it from creating its property in child scope you should use :

```
data-ng-model="$parent.search.one"
```

for better explanation on this topic please visit : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

It will clear all your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is something strange in your controller, but In this JSFiddle, selecting a new option and changing the value in the text field updates the value in `{{search}}` just fine.
https://jsfiddle.net/xx3bsafk/

Based on this other thread, mine works because the `ng-model`s in the `ng-if` fields are tied to the children of an object, not the object itself (If you were trying to edit the object itself, javascript would have automatically created a new instance of object instead of referencing the object itself - because if creates a new scope like everyone is saying.)

[Angularjs ng-model doesn't work inside ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342917/angularjs-ng-model-doesnt-work-inside-ng-if)