# After adding ng-if, I'm not able to retrive data from html to controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Here, In Ionic, I've used ng-if to display 4 input boxes per page and       clicking next will display the next 4 text boxes. However ng-model fails to   pick value if ng-if is added. Othwerwise it perfectly works fine. How to    substitute ng-if?

```
 <div class="list">
        <div ng-if="form1">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label" style="font-size:13px">BILL NO</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="regSale.billNo">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label" style="font-size:13px">BILL DATE</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="regSale.billDate">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label" style="font-size:13px">CUSTOMER NAME</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="regSale.custName">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label" style="font-size:13px">STATE</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="regSale.state">
        </label>
        <button class="button icon button-block button-royal" ng-click="callForm2()">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>

     <div ng-if="form2">
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label" style="font-size:13px">DISTRICT</span>
              <input type="text" ng-model="regSale.district">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label" style="font-size:13px">HOUSE NO.</span>
              <input type="text" ng-model="regSale.houseNo">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label" style="font-size:13px">STREET</span>
              <input type="text" ng-model="regSale.street">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label" style="font-size:13px">TEHSIL</span>
              <input type="text" ng-model="regSale.tehsil">
            </label>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col col-50">
                  <button class="button icon button-block button-calm" ng-click="callForm1()">Back</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col col-50">
                  <button class="button icon button-block button-royal" ng-click="callForm3()">Next</button>
              </div>
            </div>    
     </div>

      <div ng-if="form3"> 
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label" style="font-size:13px" >CITY/TOWN</span>
              <input type="text" ng-model="regSale.city" >
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label" style="font-size:13px" >PINCODE</span>
              <input type="text"  ng-model="regSale.pincode">
            </label>     
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label" style="font-size:13px">CONTACT</span>
              <input type="text"  ng-model="regSale.contact" >
            </label>            
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label" style="font-size:13px">PRODUCT</span>
              <input type="text"  ng-model="regSale.product" >
            </label>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col col-50">
                  <button class="button icon button-block button-calm" ng-click="callForm2()">Back</button>
              </div>

               <div class="col col-50">
                  <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="signIn(regSale)">
                    Sign-In
                  </button>
                </div>
               </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ng-if` directive creates a new scope, which may cause your `regSale` property to be assigned and defined on the child scope instead of the controller scope. Quote from [the Angular ngIf docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf):

> The scope created within ngIf inherits from its parent scope using [prototypal inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#javascript-prototypal-inheritance). An important implication of this is if ngModel is used within ngIf to bind to a javascript primitive defined in the parent scope. In this case any modifications made to the variable within the child scope will override (hide) the value in the parent scope.

Therefore, when user types in the input bind to `regSale.city`, what Angular does is effectively `childScope.regSale = {}; childScope.regSale.city = "some random city";` instead of `controllerScope.regSale.city = "some random city";`. As a result, each of the three different forms has its own scope with its own `regSale`, and the controller scope is left empty.

---

To solve this problem, you may want to define the `regSale` in your controller:

```
// In controller.js:
$scope.regSale = {};
// You don't have to change the view HTML code.
```

And then `childScope.regSale` will be exactly the same as `$scope.regSale` because of scope inheritance. Therefore the assigns will hit the same `regSale` object and work as intended.

For more information, please read the [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) section in Angular wiki. It is a little bit long, but contains a lot of examples and figures to help you understand the concepts with scopes and inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

[Angularjs ng-model doesn't work inside ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342917/angularjs-ng-model-doesnt-work-inside-ng-if)

> The ng-if directive, like other directives creates a child scope.

That's why you should use [`controller as` syntax](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller):

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl as regSale>
    <div ng-if="form1>
        <input ng-model="regSale.billNo>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could use `$scope.$parent`, but that is horrendous.

---

If you are asking for a substitute for `ng-if`, try `ng-switch`. [The easily navigable Documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)

Example in docs:

```
<ANY ng-switch="expression">
  <ANY ng-switch-when="matchValue1">...</ANY>
  <ANY ng-switch-when="matchValue2">...</ANY>
  <ANY ng-switch-default>...</ANY>
</ANY>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider wrapping each section in `<fieldset>` rather than `<div>` because you can disable a fieldset and that will disable all controls within it. Then you can use `ng-show` and `ng-disabled`

```
 <fieldset ng-show="form1" ng-disabled="!form1">
```

Alternatively put each section of the form in it's own route