# Angular ng-show doesn't work if I add ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show, angular-ng-if

I'm doing a web app with Angular which contains a table with a collapsable `tr`. But when I add some ng-if condition (if there are / are not data in the Array)the ng-show stops to work.
This is the working code without the ng-if conditions: https://plnkr.co/edit/UPFF1RboN22RAVM8r18i?p=preview

```
      <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="details-control sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="" style="width: 26px;">
        <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Projects: activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending" style="width: 306px;">Foods</th>
        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=" EST: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 84px;"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user text-muted hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i> Type</th>
        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Contacts: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 107px;">Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

<tbody ng-repeat="data in allData" >
  <tr>
      <td>
          <div class="cursor-pointer" ng-click="rows = !rows">
              <!-- <span class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-caret-down': rows, 'fa-caret-right': !rows}"></span> -->
              <p>open</p>
          </div>
      </td>
      <td>{{data.foodName}}</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{data.totalCount}}</td>
  </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="a in data.avaiable" ng-show="rows" ng-if="allData && allData.length > 0">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{a.foodType}}</td>
      <td>{{a.foodCount}}</td>
  </tr>
```

This is the not-working code with the ng-if conditions. If you see at the plk https://plnkr.co/edit/IvlIXIfWpogNi5VXo2Eh?p=preview you can notice that the rows doesn't show. Why?

Comment: in 2 cases it shows me 2 rows what is the problem?

Comment: in the second plnkr, if you click "open" it doesn show the rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cosmin** is right.

**ng-if** creates a new child scope.

you have to use `$parent` to use parent variable which you are using inside `ng-if`

change you ng-click to :

```
ng-click="$parent.rows = !rows"
```

working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qYTDcy3pShYoK0XCnGm1?p=preview)

To display **No Data Found** use other body in you table

```
<tbody ng-repeat="data in allData" >
  <tr ng-if="allData && allData.length > 0">
      <td>
          <div class="cursor-pointer" ng-click="$parent.rows = !rows">
              <!-- <span class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-caret-down': rows, 'fa-caret-right': !rows}"></span> -->
              <p>open</p>
          </div>
      </td>
      <td>{{data.foodName}}</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{data.totalCount}}</td>
  </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="a in data.avaiable" ng-show="rows" ng-if="allData && allData.length > 0">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{a.foodType}}</td>
      <td>{{a.foodCount}}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>

<!-- If there are no data -->
  <tbody ng-if="allData && (allData == null || allData.length == 0)">
       <tr>
           <td colspan="3"><span translate="generic.NO_DATA_FOUND">NO DATA FOUND</span></td>
       </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: But it doesn't display the last tr:       <tr ng-if="allData && (allData == null || allData.length == 0)">
        <td colspan="3">no data</td>
      </tr> if there are no data

Comment: I have to add the boolean where?

Comment: Ahh!!  your body have `ng-repeat="data in allData"`, so if allData is empty, yout html body not shown on page.

Answer (score 2):

As per the understanding of your requirement if you just replace the code

`ng-click="rows = !rows"` with `ng-click="data.rows = !data.rows"`

and

`ng-show="rows"` with `ng-show="data.rows"`

it must work

Comment: data.rows was never there before.. i mean in the JSON

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it doesn't work is that **ng-if** creates a new child scope thus breaking the prototypical scope inheritance.

**Must reads in order to better understand this *issue*:**

- [Angularjs ng-model doesn't work inside ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342917/angularjs-ng-model-doesnt-work-inside-ng-if).
- [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)

As a good rule of thumb, always use [controller as](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) syntax. [Here](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)'s why you should use it.

A **quick fix** for you would be to access the `rows` property from another object like this: `ng-show="container.rows"` - this way you won't break the prototypical scope inheritance. See an working example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/5tLOs3keUg1PbbcCepR3?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you @cosmin! But I didn't understand very well you quick fix

Comment: I've switched to the **quick fix** solution in which I bind the `rows` property to `data` like this: `data.rows`. You can see it working [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/5tLOs3keUg1PbbcCepR3?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check has data or not in `allData` and based on `allData` want to use `ng-repeat` then use `ng-if` condition in same element

```
<tbody ng-if="allData && allData.length > 0" ng-repeat="data in allData" >
```

instead of nested element  `<tr ng-if="allData && allData.length > 0">`

And better to use `data.rows` instead of `rows` in `ng-click` to set and in `ng-show` to show specific data rows. like: `ng-click="data.rows = !data.rows"` and `ng-show="data.rows"`

Total solution can be:

```
<table>
      <thead>
        <tr></tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody ng-if="allData && allData.length > 0" ng-repeat="data in allData" >
          <tr >
              <td>
                  <div class="cursor-pointer" ng-click="data.rows = !data.rows">
                      <p>open</p>
                  </div>
              </td>
              <td>{{data.foodName}}</td>
              .....
          </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="a in data.avaiable" ng-show="data.rows" ng-if="data.avaiable && data.avaiable.length > 0">
              ....
              <td>{{a.foodCount}}</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody ng-if="!allData || allData.length == 0">
        <tr class="yourClass">
          <td colspan="3">
             <span translate="generic.NO_DATA_FOUND"></span> 
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Super! But how can i show the       <tr ng-if="allData && (allData == null || allData.length == 0)">
        <td colspan="3"><span translate="generic.NO_DATA_FOUND"></span></td>
      </tr> if there are no data? Because it is in the same tbody