# why md-calendar directive initialize to wrong date AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

How to assign md-calendar directive date value as today Date?

[image: output of code]

```
<md-calendar class="fixed-calendar" ng-model="myDate"> 
</md-calendar>
```

how to change apr 1935 to Aug 2018 in first calendar output. please any help?
here is my working code
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RBveJv

Comment: You seem to have [this issue](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10144). It was also [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39828972/scroll-to-current-date-when-opening-md-calender).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is basically a bug in the version of `angular material v1.1.0`, there is a [`GITHUB ticket`](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/9952) with this issue details, by simply upgrading to the latest version `angular material 1.1.10` as done in the below example. We can eliminate this issue.

If you are hessitant of upgrading your angular material version, here is the [link](https://github.com/mariozelda/material/commit/266433057f40c2cc6b28c1237cec5a1a9f813c43) containing the fix details for this issue. But I strongly recommend you upgrade `angular material` instead of fixing it yourself.

Below is a working demo for your reference.

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myDate = new Date();

  $scope.minDate = new Date(
      $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
      $scope.myDate.getMonth() - 2,
      $scope.myDate.getDate());

  $scope.maxDate = new Date(
      $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
      $scope.myDate.getMonth() + 2,
      $scope.myDate.getDate());
  
  $scope.onlyWeekendsPredicate = function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return day === 0 || day === 6;
  }
});
```

```css
.datepickerdemoBasicUsage {
  /** Demo styles for mdCalendar. */ }
  .datepickerdemoBasicUsage md-content {
    padding-bottom: 200px; }

  .datepickerdemoBasicUsage .validation-messages {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: darkred;
    margin: 10px 0 0 25px; }

.fixed-calendar {
  width: 340px;
  height: 340px;
  display: block;
}

.fixed-calendar .md-calendar-scroll-mask {
  width: 340px !important;
}

.fixed-calendar .md-virtual-repeat-scroller {
  width: 340px !important;
  height: 308px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.10/angular-material.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.10/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/assets-cache.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" style="padding: 40px;"  class="datepickerdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp" ng-cloak>
  <md-content>
    <md-calendar class="fixed-calendar" ng-model="myDate">
    </md-calendar>

    <h4>Standard date-picker</h4>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>

    <h4>Disabled date-picker</h4>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" disabled=""></md-datepicker>

    <h4>Date-picker with min date and max date</h4>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-min-date="minDate" md-max-date="maxDate"></md-datepicker>
    <h4>Only weekends are selectable</h4>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-date-filter="onlyWeekendsPredicate"></md-datepicker>

    <h4>Only weekends within given range are selectable</h4>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-min-date="minDate" md-max-date="maxDate" md-date-filter="onlyWeekendsPredicate"></md-datepicker>
    
    <h4>With ngMessages</h4>
    <form name="myForm">
      <md-datepicker name="dateField" ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" required="" md-min-date="minDate" md-max-date="maxDate" md-date-filter="onlyWeekendsPredicate"></md-datepicker>

      <div class="validation-messages" ng-messages="myForm.dateField.$error">
        <div ng-message="valid">The entered value is not a date!</div>
        <div ng-message="required">This date is required!</div>
        <div ng-message="mindate">Date is too early!</div>
        <div ng-message="maxdate">Date is too late!</div>
        <div ng-message="filtered">Only weekends are allowed!</div>
      </div>
    </form>
    
  </md-content>
</div>
```

Comment: @NandhiniPriya Could you please check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/kai1992cool/pen/oMVERM)

Answer (score 0):

If you are hessitant of upgrading your angular material version

try something like this in controller

```
$scope.datepickeropen = function(){
    $timeout(function () {
        var e1 = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        e1.which = 40; // it is down
        $(".md-datepicker-calendar .md-focus").trigger(e1);
        var e2 = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        e2.which = 38; // it is up
        $(".md-datepicker-calendar .md-focus").trigger(e2);
    },500)
}
```

HTML as

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>Withdrawal Date</label>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="date" ng-focus="datepickeropen()"></md-datepicker>
</md-input-container>
```

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.myDate = new Date();
  $scope.datepickeropen = function(){
      $timeout(function () {
          var e1 = jQuery.Event("keydown");
          e1.which = 40; // it is down
          $(".md-datepicker-calendar .md-focus").trigger(e1);
          var e2 = jQuery.Event("keydown");
          e2.which = 38; // it is up
          $(".md-datepicker-calendar .md-focus").trigger(e2);
      },500)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.1/angular-material.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/assets-cache.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" style="padding: 40px;"  class="datepickerdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp" ng-cloak>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>

<h4>Standard date-picker <u>with issue fixed</u></h4>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-hide-icons="triangle" ng-focus="datepickeropen()"></md-datepicker>
    
    <h4>Standard date-picker <u>with issue</u></h4>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-hide-icons="triangle"></md-datepicker>
    

</div>
```