# Spring and Json field mapping that can be String or Boolean

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, json, spring

I have a String `value` field inside my object, but this field can be even true or false. Now the mapping create `value: "true"` like a `String` and this create problem with some angularjs `ng-model` mapping because it wants a `boolean`.
There is a way to indicate to `Spring`/`Jackson` that the `String` with true or false must be without `""`?
Or you have some advice to converte easly this value to boolean?
At the moment I'm initializing the value through javascript with code like this

```
if ($(element)[0].value == "true")
   $(element).iCheck('check');
else
   $(element).iCheck('update');
```

but it is a work-around and I have a problem with value change (I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47092037/angularjs-directive-icheck-doesnt-capture-the-first-switch-from-true-to-false)). 
The only solution is to change this value into javascript?
Thanks

Comment: Why not change the filed to boolean?

Comment: it can be string-number or boolean, with string I can have one single field instead before that I used three different field but it complicates the code

Comment: @luca see the edit to my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can [customize how your data is serialized in Jackson](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization). Then you can simply return the value as a boolean from the server.

---

EDIT re: 3 field vs string comment above

This is exactly what you should be handling on the server side with what your controller is returning. Make use of that layer and convert the value in a Jackson Mapper or straight up in the data access layer (makes your model consistent from that layer up).

Answer (score 0):

in java script you can use `JSON.parse("true")` it is return boolean value

`console.log(true==JSON.parse("true")) //true`