# Wrapping an input with ng-if sends an empty value

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```html
  <div layout="row" layout-align="center" ng-if="!sort">
    <div class="sort" layout-padding flex=50 layout-align="center" layout="column">
      <input class="searchInput" ng-model="searchText" ng-model-options='{ debounce: 600 }' ng-change="search()">
    </div>
  </div>
```

When `sort` is not set, the input is shown correctly (and hidden when `sort` is set), but when entering text into the input, `$scope.searchText` is `undefined`.

If I remove the ng-if, everything works correctly.

Comment: [Angularjs ng-model doesn't work inside ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342917/angularjs-ng-model-doesnt-work-inside-ng-if). `ng-if` creates its own scope, try reaching for a parent's scope with `ng-model="$parent.searchText"`

Comment: Have you tried with `ng-hide` instead? `ng-if` removes totally from DOM and clones to re-insert. Maybe that's the cause?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey That works, is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: as Kaddath mentioned, `ng-if` removes DOM completely (which can be slow), so alternative is to use `ng-hide` / `ng-show` that just hides it and doesn't create any problems with scopes

Comment: Another question resolved in the comments section...

Comment: @gyc it was a potential duplicate in the first place `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs ng-model doesn't work inside ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342917/angularjs-ng-model-doesnt-work-inside-ng-if)