# AngularJS data-ng-model works only in the same <div>

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Coming from Angular6, I am trying to make this work in a custom directive. I have a checkbox, if the checkbox is checked it displays the next block otherwise it does not.

I never did angularJS before and I really have no idea why `isAlsoMagic` changes is only detected in the first `<div>`. Going through the doc I could not find the explanation, any one knows ?

beautiful.html :

```
      <div ng-if="isMagicDog" class="someClass">
          <div class="formattingClass">
              <!-- display formatting -->
          </div>
          <input id="someId" type="checkbox" name="someName" data-ng-model="isAlsoMagic">
          Is he magic ? {{isAlsoMagic}}
          </input>
        <div ng-if="isAlsoMagic">
            This is working well {{isAlsoMagic}}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div ng-if="isAlsoMagic">
          This is not working, isAlsoMagic is not modified after clicking on the checkbox {{isAlsoMagic}}
      </div>
```

JS  : 
import template from './beautiful.html';

```
angular
  .module('magicApp')
  .directive('beautiful', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        param1: '=',
        param2: '=?'
      },
      template,
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, NotBeautifulCtrl, $parent) {
        scope.param1= (scope.param1 === 'true');
        scope.param2= NotBeautifulCtrl.param2;
        scope.isMagicDog= true;
        scope.isAlsoMagic = true;
        }
    };
  });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128323/if-you-are-not-using-a-dot-in-your-angularjs-models-you-are-doing-it-wrong

Comment: try to use ControllerAs , and ng-model="$ctrl.yourdata"

Comment: Can you explain what will it do? Reading your link I did not understand sorry

Comment: I just found the answer there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342917/angularjs-ng-model-doesnt-work-inside-ng-if